# Python and special charactes

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8, ascii

I am developing on Windows 7 (64-bit)

I have a text file with special characters inside
[image: see display in hexa]

When I ask python for the coding it says ascii.
I have tried to replace the special characters `EF BF BD` by programming and converting.

```
f = codecs.open(path, "r", "utf-8")
line_brut = f.read()
# line has bad chars
print(line_brut)

#ignore chars
ascii_line = line_brut.encode("ascii", "ignore")
print(ascii_line)

# pas bon le e disparait
uni_decode = unidecode(line_brut)
print(uni_decode)
```

I have tested several methods but no success

Comment: have you tried `line_brut.decode("utf-8"))` ? (decode not encode). and what's the expected output? could you paste the hex bytes as text instead of images BTW?

Comment: ^ Especially *what is the expected output*? Without knowing what you expect those bytes to represent, all we can do is guess; same as Python.

Comment: I expect to have the letter 'e' in ascii

Comment: I have tried the suggestion with decode, but it returns an error:

Comment: The error is:UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufeff' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)